# How can I merge Shelve files/databases?

Tags: python, database, shelve

I have several Shelve i.e. .db files that I wish to merge together into one single database.

The only method I could think of was to iterate through each database rewriting each iteration to the new database, but this takes too long.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That is effectively what *any* way would have to do. It's kind of like asking for `max()` function which runs in less than O(n) time for an unsorted list.

Answer (score 0):

Shelves are mappings, and mappings have an `update()` method.